# Image byte array is not saving properly

Tags: c#

I want to save an image that exist in picture box as a byte array to the database.I am new to programming so please help me to resolve this. Everytime I save my image byte array in the database, it always shows the same byte array. `0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D` but this is what I see always in the database. No matter which image I save, it will always saves this code: `0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D`. Please help me to resolve this issue.

This is my code

```
Byte[] imgBytes = null;
ImageConverter imgConverter = new ImageConverter();
imgBytes = 
(System.Byte[])imgConverter.ConvertTo(PictureBox1.Image,Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"));
```

Comment: Have a look at this article! http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20020929.asp

Comment: This code is not the problem. your problem is else where, please double check all your code, debug it, make sure you have debugged this

Answer (score 5):

To save an image, use [Image.Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2)

ImageConverter is not for converting image to binary.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
PictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
```